# Rails 2 error setting Time.zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, timezone

I have the following setup:

'config/environment.rb'

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

'application_controller.rb'

```
before_fiter :set_timezone

def set_timezone
  session[:time_zone] = current_user.time_zone # => 'Brasilia'
  Time.zone = session[:time_zone] 
end
```

But, on my view side, when I try:

```
<%= Time.zone.now %>
```

It returns the timezone that I setted on my 'environment.rb' and not the one present on the session value.

Any idea?

Comment: Apperently this seems to be an issue in rails 2. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722144/time-zone-weirdness-in-rails